# Scala Future with side-affect best practice

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, jvm

In case I would like my Scala Future to return a value, the execution can be guaranteed by Await result / ready, for example -

```
   def longCalculation: Int = {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    42
  }

  implicit val executionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global

  val aFuture: Future[Int] = Future {  
    longCalculation
//        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException // non-fatal exception
//        throw new StackOverflowError() // fatal exception
  }
```

evaluate Future which returns concrete value -

```
  val ready_aFuture_1: Future[Int] = Await.ready(aFutureTest, Duration.Inf)
  val ready_aFuture_2: Option[Try[Int]] = ready_aFuture_1.value
  val ready_aFuture_3: Try[Int] = ready_aFuture_2.get // will never be None, Option is unnecessary.
  val ready_aFuture_4: String = ready_aFuture_3 match {
    case Success(t) => t.toString
    case Failure(e) => e.toString
  }
  println(ready_aFuture_4)
```

And in case I would like to manipulate side effect with future, the only way I could find which can guaranteed the execution is -

```
val f: Future[Unit] = aFuture.map{ v =>
    println(s"the result of aFuture map is: $v")
  }

   Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
```

But that's pretty ugly, both because I used .map for "side-effect" and because we need to keep and use the type `Unit`.
Is there any other approach to guaranteed processing of a Future which produce "side-effect"?

Comment: I am not sure why you think `map` or `Unit` are "ugly". Both seem fine to me. Or ue `andThen` as suggested in the answer (I find it less convenient, because it takes a `Try`, but sometimes it is actually useful, depends on how you want to handle failures). The "ugliest" piece in your snippet in my book is `Await` ... In most cases, well-designed code should not have to explicitly wait for a side effect to happen (if you need to wait for it, it's not really a side effect). But, that's, of course, "opinion-based", so I am voting to close this question :)

Comment: I think map is ugly because in pure functional programming map shouldn’t produce side-effect, rather then foreach. Furthermore I don’t agree that in well designed code I shouldn’t explicitly execute Wait because wait’s purpose is for guaranteed, I mean that in my real scenario programming problem, in 99% of the cases it won’t be needed, but in production process we have to guarantee our execution.

Comment: In _pure_ functional programming there are no side effects :) Once you have a side effect, it is not pure, the name of the function that produces it doesn't matter. In any case, if you don't like `map`, just use `andThen` as suggested.  I don't know what you mean exactly by "having to guarantee execution", but the proper way to guarantee the presence of a side effect, if to look at the side effect, not block the thread waiting for a function to return ... nothing (not to imply blocking would be much more justified if it actually returned something useful).

Comment: WDYM with the execution can be guaranteed? BTW, maybe you want to use `foreach` instead?

Comment: I mean that we have to guarantee that the side-effect method has been executed and finished the execution before we quit the main thread. foreach is not sufficient because the main thread can be ended before the foreach did.

Comment: Well, if this is just for the main thread you can just `Await` on the future that produces some value and then perform the side effect after the `Await` without using `Future` anymore. - BTW, for the way you speak, it seems you would rather prefer to use `IO` from **cats-effect** rather than `Future`

Comment: Thanks Luis, but you got me all wrong. Let’s leave it, the other guys gave some meaningful respone.

Comment: Well, maybe you should improve your communication skills then. Also, as Dima said, there is nothing wrong nor ugky with using `map` with `Future` for a side-effect, because `Future` was not created to manage side-effects, is just a mechanism to handle callbacks; that is why I suggested looking into **cats-effect** - Anyways, if `andThen` solves your question _(whatever that was)_ then please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: It’s not about communication skill rather then understanding Functional Programing צconcepts and terminology. I’m still waiting to see if anyone else has another solution.

Comment: Again `Future` is not a functional programming construct _(at least not a pure one which is the definition you are using)_, so you can not apply that rationale over it. Also, your question is still not clear.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you want to use `andThen`. The scala doc says:

> Applies the side-effecting function to the result of this future, and returns a new future with the result of this future.

So, for instance, you can write:

```
val f: Future[Int] = aFuture.andThen { v =>
  println(s"the result of aFuture map is: $v")
}
Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
```